# Implement Restful api in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I'm new to node.js and my question is quite a dumb one. I have created my restful api that does something but the problem is i have to call server.js file in the cmd. I want to create file called client.js that request the service from server.js and server.js will perform the job and return the result to client.js which will be shown to user.

Comment: I don't see a problem yet? do you not want to call server.js?

Comment: I want to call the server.js but via client.js.

Comment: What I'm doing right now is node server.js and i get the result.                       it shoud be like node client.js---->server.js and server.js returns the result to client.js. I actually dont know how to do it :(

Comment: I didn't know client.js is also server end code. Why do you need it to be this way, why can't server be running and client requesting when it needs to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to communicate via JSON data. When client accesses some url in `server` application, server application should provide data in JSON format.

Example - Server provides a list of people who have registered to your site. Than code your server in such a way that when client accesses `www.example.com/accounts/users` (where www.example.com is where your server is running), server should return a JSON response which client can than use to display.